# jqGrid edittype select css class

Tags: css, select, jqgrid

how can I set a css class to the  element jqgrid creates by using edittype: select? Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
            GetProjects();
        });

        function GetProjects() {
            jQuery("#tbl1").jqGrid({
                url: 'myurl',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames: ['Project', 'Module', 'Description'],
                colModel: [
        { name: 'Project', index: 'Name', width: 90, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: GetProjectOptions()} },
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Project.Name', width: 55, editable: true },
        { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 90, editable: true }
    ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#nav1',
                sortname: 'Project.Name',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "DDS Project Modules",
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function (obj) { return obj; }
                },
                width: '500',
                loadonce: true,
                hidegrid: false,
                editurl: 'myurl'
            });
            jQuery("#tbl1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#nav1', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
        }

        function AddRow() {
            jQuery("#tbl1").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", { reloadAfterSubmit: false, closeAfterAdd: true });
        }
```

I've tried using classes: 'cssClass' in the colModel but that didn't work.
Here is how the html is created:

```
<select name="Project" class="FormElement" id="Project" role="select" size="1">
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `dataInit` method of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). For example you can try the following code

```
editoptions: {
    value: GetProjectOptions(),
    dataInit: function (elem) {
        $(elem).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    }
}
```

The result will be like the following:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It works and I can now set a class to the element. I'm marking your answer as solution but I have one more question. I followed your example and while it did set my class and added some modifications, the result is not the same as your example. You can find my result here: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/442/demoy.png/). It seems like the arrow was not changed. Is it a theme thing? What theme did you use in your example?

Comment: @FlorinBombeanu: It's just differences in the web browsers. You used IE or Firefox and I used Google Chrome for the screenshort.

Comment: Took a look in the applied css styles and nothing seems to change my arrow. I've tested this using IE, Chrome and Firefox with the same result. I'm still thinking it's the theme. I've tested with Redmond and Lightness. I'll keep digging. Thanks.